# VS Code: Snippet selection escaping of "no character"

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-extensions

I try to create a snippet where the *NOCHAR* inserts is empty. When the user selects this entry there should be NO character (not even a space).
--> just to define|,a,b,c| is not really working.

```
"Library.Internal":
{
    "prefix": "SYSTEM.Library.Internal",
    "description": "Insert command for label/value from internal library.\r",
    "body": 
    [
        "# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
        "«LIB(${1|*NOCHAR*,a,b,c|)»",
        ""
    ]
},
```

Is there a way to do that? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I think you might get is to try:

```
    "«LIB${1|(,(a,(b,(c|})»",
```

It isn't that pretty but the first choice merely adds the left parenthesis with no argument as you wish.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Sadly this is not an option for me because the brakets are not "optional".

I also guess there wont be a closer aproach as yours :/

Comment: The brackets are in all options - so they are always included in whichever you pick.